# What happens an iOS App after the debugging on the device is finished?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I am not yet a member of the iOS Developer Program. I am familiar with the fact that all Apps on non jailbreaked iOS Devices must be downloaded from the App Store. But what about my own Apps I developed and tested on my iOS device. Do they remain on the device after I finished debugging so I am able to show the Apps some friends without having my iPhone or iPad connected to Xcode on my Mac?

Thanks
ksman

Answer (score 1):

Apps that were put on a device have an associated provisioning profile.  Each provisioning profile has an expiration date after which the app it is associated with will no longer run.

If I recall correctly, development profiles expire after 3 months and ad hoc distribution profiles expire after 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they remain on the device and are usable like any app until the corresponding development profile expires.